# How to use different input types for one entity CollectionType - Symfony 3

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, types, field

*in Symfony 3.2.4 and PHP 5.6.28*

I'm making a Survey system in a dedicated Bundle.
I have 3 entities Question / Answer / Survey

**SurveyType is based on 2 CollectionType** : One contains questions, the other answers.

*SurveyType :*

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add(
            'question',
            CollectionType::class,
            array(
                'entry_type' => QuestionType::class)
        )
         ->add(
             'answer',
             CollectionType::class,
             array(
                 'entry_type' => AnswerType::class,
         )
     );
```

Everything is working so far if I only need text or numbers as answer.

The problem is that I need **different** "Answer Input Type" : Checkbox, Range, Text ... for each question.

The "Answer Field Type" that I need is stored in DB table Question.

[question.table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr91v.jpg)

When generate my form in controller I can only have one input type.

```
 $form = $this->createForm(SurveyType::class, $survey, array(
        'question_type' => 'range'
    ));
```

For exemple all of my answers can only be Range or Text. I can't mix answer input type.
[Only Range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYvzH.jpg)

**Is there a way to say : "For question (1) I want my answer to be a string but question (2) I want a range" and they are all part of the same SurveyForm ?**

Comment: Are you sure this works? Have you tried for multiple questions/answers? It looks to me like this will render a collection of questions, then will render a collection of answers. It seems you should build a form with a single question and answer combo, then render a collection of those single forms. The single forms could then each implement the solution I suggest below with a a form event subscriber to render question/answer combos of the correct input type.

Comment: I need to have only one form on my view (one survey). That's why i have 2 collectionType : for answers and questions.  I'm using specific js and css that can't work with multiple survey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the form dynamically based on the answer type needed. See the docs page [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html). You'll have to add some logic in the event subscriber class to return an input of the correct type.